# I am writing a program that should embed a path of a resource from my IIS

Tags: ms-word

I am writing a program that should embed a path of a resource from my IIS directory into a word document that should access that file from IIS and that file should not be visible to the user.

I am using C# as programming language

Comment: And what's your question, exactly?

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister, Actually I was developing a document security tool that secures a document in that way If anybody open it on the system his I should be notified that who has opened it. I have got the solution, Thanks for your intervention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As when somebody access any resource of from IIS that captures the footprint of who so ever has accessed it so I embedded the image into the document grammatically so whenever the document was opened i was notified.

I got idea for here https://forums.iis.net/t/1189869.aspx?how+to+track+list+of+IP+address+of+visitors+by+IIS+

Thanks again